# Web services SOAP, REST diferencias, configuración

Tags: .net, rest, soap, wcf

Estoy viendo algunos temas para comunicar datos entre aplicaciones, y a raíz de leer mucho, se me formó un enredo de conceptos.

Sé que dentro de los métodos de comunicación, lo más usado hoy en dia, son los servicios web, de los cuales hay 2 tipos (al menos en .net) que son, SOAP, y REST. También sé que estos métodos no son propios de la tecnología .NET.

El tema es, que tengo un servicio hecho con "VS2015 Profesional Edition", para lo cual creé un nuevo proyecto del tipo WFC-Biblioteca de servicios.
Existe además otra plantilla, que se llama Aplicación de servicios.

Mi pregunta es, con estas plantillas, **¿estoy creando un servicio web REST o SOAP?**

Mi segunda pregunta es, como genero mi servicio, con WSDL, para los clientes que lo van a ver en la red (red interna).

Espero me puedan ayudar al respecto, porque estoy un poco confundido entre tanta información que existe.

Comment: No soy un experto en el tema así que dejaré a otro que te explique las diferencias. Solo te diré dos cosa, una que SOAP tiende a usarse cada vez menos en favor de REST (en proyecto nuevos, se entiende), y que para crear un REST en .NET debes crear una [Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) ;)

Comment: Tu post tiene varias preguntas, algunas hechas de manera directa, otras de manera indirecta. 

Lo recomendable en StackOverflow es tener una sola pregunta por POST, para que de esta manera puedas seleccionar la respuesta correcta de manera mas fácil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOAP es un protocolo, REST es un tipo de arquitectura, forzando un poco las cosas, incluso podrías hacer REST sobre SOAP.

SOAP es un protocolo que usa mensajes basados en XML para estructurar la información, y como transporte puede usar HTTP (lo más común), SMTP, JMS o cualquier otro protocolo de comunicación.

Un WSDL es, de manera muy resumida, una especificación en XML que describe la funcionalidad que tiene disponible el servicio web. Generalmente se usa en conjunto con SOAP.

La definición super simplificada de REST: es un diseño (o estilo) de arquitectura que representa a todos los recursos a través de URI's y las operaciones se manejan por verbos de HTTP (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...), algo así como una sesión de browser normal.

Sobre WCF, lo tradicional es SOAP sobre algún protocolo de transporte, pero las últimas versiones también soportan JSON para servicios tipo REST.

Sobre tus preguntas, lo más seguro es que sea SOAP,y el WSDL se genera de manera automática poniendo **?wsdl** al final del URL del servicio.

UPDATE:

@Byron tiene un punto muy importante, ya metiéndose en el detalle técnico, es importante definir `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>` para que el wsdl se genere de manera automática

Comment: es importante mencionar que para que el WSDL de un servicio WCF se genere debe estar configurado  el meta   `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>`. El WSDL es para servicios SOAP.

Comment: @Byron, tienes razón, lo agregaré al texto

Comment: Estimados, muchas gracias por sus aportes a este tema.. la verdad, es que a veces entre tantas especificaciones es dificil no perderse. Como aporte adicional, les remito esta pagina, donde encontre una muy buena explicacion entre web services y wcf. https://infoinnova.net/2011/11/wcfvsaspnet/

Comment: Si, y además cambian tan rápido las especificaciones que la dificultad de mantenerse actualizado se incrementa.